# Указание ресурса тексту

Tags: activity, android

При использовании setText если я укажу выставить @string/myText, то выставиться не содержимое данного ресурса, а сама фраза "@string/myText". **А как выставить тексту содержимое какого-то ресурса?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо  "@string/myText" пиши getResources().getString(R.string.myText);

аналогично для других ресурсов

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.setText(R.string.myText);
```